# Css/html: Unable to change the height on this div

Tags: html, css

[Hey, everyone!  I'm having issues with changing the height of this container in the .top-container div I created.  I can change the width just fine but the height won't change. Can someone help please?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F1q2.png)

Comment: No one wants to write out all your code. Hence, screenshots are not permitted. Please provide [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @kameron sorry I didn't know.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. From the latter, "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: Just copy your code and insert it into a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) which is provided in the question area. See the `<>` button.

Comment: @Kameron Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Because you've used  instead of  this as you've used ".top-container" in CSS not **.top-container;** . Avoid using ;(semicolon) in class.

Comment: Please read [answer], especially the part titled "Answer well-asked questions".

Answer (score -1):

You have got a typo in your HTML code.

```
<div class="top-container;">
```

Remove this `;` to correctly target the class in your CSS.

Comment: Please read [answer], especially the part titled "Answer well-asked questions".